# Spark: Splitting using delimiter doesn't work with commas

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delimiter

I am working on Spark SQL with Spark(2.2) and using Java API for loading data from a CSV file.

In the CSV file there is quotes inside cells, the column separater is a pipe |.

Line example: `2012|"Hello|World"`

This my code for reading a CSV and returning Dataset:

```
session = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row>=session.read().option("header", "true").option("delimiter", |).csv(filePath);
```

This is what I got

```
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
|Year |       c1     |               c2         |
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
|2012 |Hello|World   +              null        |
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
```

The expected result is this:

```
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
|Year |       c1     |               c2         |
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
|2012 |"Hello        +              World"      |
+-----+--------------+--------------------------+
```

The only thing I can think of is deleting the commas ' " ', but this out of question because I dont want to change the values of the cells.

I would appreciate any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 Dataset<Row> test = spark.read()
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("delimiter", "|")
.option("quote", " ")
.load(filePath);
```